# Typescript Object is possible undefined for Codepipeline SDK v3

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a simple function which calculation codepipeline execution ID inside lambda. However I am not able to pass typescript check as in the original implementation of the package object is optional.

```
async function getPipelineExecutionId(pipelineName: string): Promise<string> {
  const pipelineParams = {
    name: pipelineName,
  };
  const codePipelineClient = new CodePipelineClient({ region: region });
  const codePipelineCommand = new GetPipelineStateCommand(pipelineParams);
  const pipelineInfo = await codePipelineClient.send(codePipelineCommand);

  const executionId = pipelineInfo.stageStates[2].latestExecution.pipelineExecutionId //ts error

  return executionId
}
```

Error

```
'pipelineInfo.stageStates' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Comment: This is the expected behaviour.  Typescript is warning that your code may try to index `undefined`, which is an error.

Comment: so it is normal keep it like that? Is it a good practice ? Howdy we remove this warning?

Comment: Well, you might start by searching for [\[typescript\] object is possibly undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+object+is+possibly+undefined) on SO.